# PostgreSQL order by month name on distinction

Tags: postgresql

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (tours.departure.departure_month)
                   tours.departure.departure_month
FROM tours.departure
```

But I want to order the distinct months by month name. I've tried this from a similar question `to_date(tours.departure.departure_month, 'Month')`,
but I cannot get it to work with `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: The query you have is identical to `SELECT DISTINCT tours.departure.departure_month FROM tours.departure`. Can you describe in more detail (perhaps with an example) what you need?

Comment: i need to `ORDER BY` the result by the month name, in another question i found the answer to that is to user this `ORDER BY to_date(tours.departure.departure_month, 'Month')`
but this won't work with distinct, it works if you remove the distinct

Comment: Describe "won't work".

Comment: it gives this error `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`

Answer (score 0):

What is the column type of departure_month is it date or month names, if its date type column you can try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (tours.departure.departure_month)
       tours.departure.departure_month
FROM tours.departure
ORDER BY month(tours.departure.departure_month) DESC;
```

Comment: it's a text column, i will try to alter it into a date and try your suggestion